# Создание .bat файла для запуска .exe с доп. параметром

Tags: windows, bat, cmd, консоль, netbeans

Мне нужно запустить программу NetBeans с дополнительным параметром. Вот работающий вариант через консоль по шагам:

```
>b:
>cd "Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\bin"
>netbeans64.exe --locale en:US
```

однако этот вариант очень громоздкий, плюс ко всему закрытие консоли закрывает саму программу. Я попробовал написать .bat-файл:

```
@echo off
echo Netbeans
start "netbeans" "b:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\bin\netbeans64.exe --locale en:US"
pause
exit
```

это решение, однако, не работает, сообщает, что не может найти то, что я хочу. Знаю, что задача простая, но с написанием таких файлов никогда не сталкивался. Поэтому нужна помощь - плз., просто напишите, что надо исправить. Буду очень признателен.

Comment: >сообщает, что не может найти то, что я хочу

Прямо так и пишет: "не могу найти что вы хотите"? Или всё-таки что-то поконкретней?

Comment: В общем, ваше предположение верно. Оформите его как ответ, плз, я его зафиксирую. Вот наиболее полный вариант: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20709345/cant-execute-exe-with-an-additional-param-using-the-bat-file/20709446?noredirect=1#comment31023918_20709446

Comment: Скорее всего русский язык не принимает

Comment: Рад, что вопрос решился - но что мешало сделать ярлык на NetBeans с указанием этого самого параметра?

Comment: Если это действительно вопрос к автору, то лучше оставить его в виде комментария. Если это ответ, то возможно лучше подходит более утвердительная форма, например: "Вместо создания bat-файла, можно создать ярлык с указанием необходимых параметров.  <пару слов, почему ярлык здесь лучше/хуже bat-файла> и вот инструкция как это сделать (ссылка на доки)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего ошибка в том, что путь к программе в команде `start` содержит пробелы и не заключен отдельно в кавычки. Пробуйте так:

```
start "netbeans" "b:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\bin\netbeans64.exe" --locale en:US
```