# Запуск WinForm с параметром

Tags: c#, cmd

Всем привет, написал приложение на WinForm, в котором есть пункт запуск с параметром, в приложении обработал это так

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    if (args.Length == 1 && args[0] == "Show Version")
    {
        var result = MessageBox.Show(" ", "...", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        if  (result == DialogResult.OK) Environment.Exit(0);
    }
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

через cmd запустить не получается проверяю через .bat файл

```
path C:\Users\И\Desktop\с#\test\test\bin\Debug\
start test.exe /Show Version
pause
start test.exe --Show Version
pause
```

пробовал и в кавычки параметр засунуть и без, может в коде приложения косяк? пробовал через ярлык на рабочем столе в св-вах объекта указать, подскажите как с параметром запустить? 
[Создание .bat файла для запуска .exe с доп. параметром](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/281883/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-bat-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-exe-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC)
Эту статью читал через -- тоже писал не выходит

Comment: не уверен по поводу c#, но обычно args[0] - это имя запускаемой программы. скорее всего надо проверять так: args.Length == 2 && args[1] == "Show Version"

Comment: @Александр в C# нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
start test.exe "Show Version"
```

Учтите, что команды автоматически разбиваются **по пробелам**. Ваша `start test.exe /Show Version` будет разбита как `["/Show", "Version"]`. В дебаггере вы с легкостью могли бы проверить аргументы, которые получаете.

К слову, чтобы упростить жизнь и не подключатся дебаггером к проекту, можете скомпилировать код, вставив некоторый `MessageBox`, который выводил бы список полученных аргументов:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MessageBox.Show(String.Empty, String.Join(Environment.NewLine, args, MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    ...
}
```

Либо, если вы используете Visual Studio в свойствах проекта, можно указать входные параметры и запускать под дебаггом:

[image: !]

Comment: про messageBox хорошая идея ща все протестирую

Comment: start test.exe "Show Version" <br/>
pause <br/>